# R igraph convert parallel edges to weight attribute

Tags: r, igraph, edges, weighted-graph

I'm working with igraph for R. My graph is based on an edgelist which includes parallel edges (more than one edge with the same source and target). I would like to convert these parallel edges to an edge attribute weight. Is there an eay way to do this?

If there is no easy way. how can I identify these parallel edges?

```
    duplicated(E(net))
```

does not return a single duplicate. I suppose its looking for duplicated edge ids.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can also use `E(graph)$weight <- 1` followed by `simplify(graph, edge.attr.comb=list(weight="sum"))` to assign a weight of 1 to each edge and then collapsing multiple edges into single ones while summing the weights.

Comment: This solution is actually much better, because it uses linear space and time, whereas the adjacency matrix solution uses quadratic (in terms of the number of vertices) space and time.

Comment: Btw. this also eliminates loop edges, so if you don't want that, use the `remove.loops=FALSE` argument to `simplify()`.

Answer (score 5):

It seems exporting an unweighted graph with parallel edges to an adjacency matrix in `igraph` creates a weights list with the number of edges as weight, which can then be read again:

```
library("igraph")
E <- matrix(c(1,1,1,2,2,2),3,2)
G <- graph.edgelist(E)

G2 <- graph.adjacency(get.adjacency(G),weighted=TRUE)
```

Comment: This is a really helpful solution for very large graphs.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to get the number of parallel edges of a graph without adding a weight attribute to your graph, you could use the following function:

```
duplicated <- function(graph){
  g_local <- graph
  E(g_local)$weight <- 1
  g_simp <- simplify(g_local, edge.attr.comb=list(weight="sum"))
  w <- E(g_simp)$weight
  return(sum(w-1))
}
```